# Is there a procedure to give a generating function for arbitrary regular languages?

Tags: generating-functions, formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

The [Schützenberger methodology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtzenberger_enumeration_theorem) can enumerate the number of words of given length $k$ for unambiguous context free languages by a generating function. But not all regular languages are *unambiguous* context free languages, so the Schützenberger methodology can not be applied to them.

My question: Is there a procedure to give for every regular language a generating function that enumerates the number of words of length $k$ of this language?

Comment: I was under the impression (?) that all regular languages are unambiguous context-free as well - transforming a DFA into a right-linear grammar gives an unambiguous grammar for the language. Or am I mistaken about this?

Comment: @templatetypedef: since every regular language can be recognised by a deterministic finite state automaton, it is certainly unambiguous; an unambiguous grammar can be read directly off of the DFA. But that only tells you that an algebraic generating function exists. Unless you have a regular grammar for the language, it might not be possible to establish what that generating function is. At least, that's my understanding.

Comment: [This question on cstheory.se](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8200/counting-words-accepted-by-a-regular-grammar) seems relevant.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I just grabbed the statement somewhere that there are ambiguous regular languages - without checking it. So my premise might be mistaken, thanks for correcting it in this case.

Comment: @nici: My understanding of the Schützenberger methodology was that one can effectively establish a generating function, given an unambiguous context-free language. What did I get wrong?

Comment: @rici My impression was that the grammars obtained by the most straightforward transformations of DFAs into CFGs are indeed regular grammars (they're either right-linear or left-linear, depending on how you do the transform). Is that correct?

Comment: @templatetypedef: yes. Such a grammar is a direct implementation of the state transitions, so it must be unambiguous because the FA is D. So if you have a DFA, you're good to go. But you might just have some description of a set which an oracle tells you is regular. Or a non-regular grammar which you are told produces a regular language. The procedure for turning that into an algebraic generating function is less clear.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker: Chomsky&Schützenberger proved that an algebraic generating function exists. That's different from saying that the generating function is discoverable. The Schützenberger methodology transforms an unambiguous context-free *grammar* into an algebraic generating function. But while all regular languages have unambiguous context-free grammars, not every grammar for a regular language is unambiguous. And it is not decidable whether a given grammar is unambiguous, nor whether it is equivalent to another grammar.

Comment: It's important to always keep present the difference between a property of a *grammar* and a property with the same name of a *language*. Usually we say that language $L$ has property $P$ iff $\exists G | L(G) = L \land P(G)$; that is, if *some* grammar for $L$ has property $P$.